# How to redirect elgantly many redirects in htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, redirect, rewrite

**Q1.** is it possible to further **optimize** / **compact** the following rules, thereby making the entire redirections **faster** and easier to maintain in future? There are about twenty of these domains!! you get the picture of my problem!  Thanks very much for any and all clues +1

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
RewriteRule ^$ en/home [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.de$
RewriteRule ^$ de/home [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.fr$
RewriteRule ^$ fr/home [R=301]
```

etc etc etc
**Q2.** should I chain these rules like putting [C] at end or ??

**Q3.** is this the proper fashion of redirecting from search engine point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to **Q1**, the only way I can think of making it a bit more compact is to make part of your on-disk path to the sites reflect the url - that way you can probably get away with a handful of rules just to take the domain suffix and apply it to the path.

For **Q2**, I'd say it looks fine, although I'd add `,L` to the `[R=301]`, so it reads `[R=301,L]` - that'll stop mod_rewrite from going any further once it's found a match.

Lastly, for **Q3** I think you're spot on with **301** - Google recommend using 301 Redirects, as [this document](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) on their site says.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Andy! all my questions are answered, the Fourth Question i have put in a separate page, as its about COMBINING multiple domains that all go to the same page, unlike the nature of this question where they are all spread,  http://serverfault.com/questions/214211/compact-redirects-in-apache-htaccess-how-an-elegant-coding-question